# Removing text + shortcode from all posts

Tags: shortcode

I want to remove certain shortcode and text that I manually placed in all my posts from the start but I really don't want to go through every post and remove it manually if I don't have to.

The shortcode is a for an ad and the text just says advert. I just want to remove it from every post if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow these steps:

1. Export your database, save a duplicate of it
2. Open the database in a text editor, I use Sublime
3. Search for that [shortcode] and text and remove those (can replace them with a backspace or anything else you want)
4. Save that edited database
5. Create a new database and upload this new data file to it, then link your site to it (I recommend this so you can go back to the original database if something goes wrong)

Comment: I found these plugins.
Do you think any of these could do what I wanted?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-search-replace/
https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/search-and-replace
https://wordpress.org/plugins/text-replace/screenshots/

Sorry, it might seem obvious but I'm not an expert at this kind of thing!

Comment: Sure use this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-search-replace/ and also this one to back up your database first before running the operation with Safe Search and Replace: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-db-backup/installation/

Comment: Hi, do you think this one could do it also? https://wordpress.org/plugins/text-replace/

That last one you chose looks like it shows every post that was changed after you click it to make changes. I have many MANY posts and that would probably crash the system showing that many changes

Comment: Remember I'm not recommending any plugins for this, those are the ones you chose. Do you have access to your database? This is the easiest, fastest, and best way to do it.

Comment: I know you are not recommending any plugins and I wouldn't hold it against you if one of them did any damage as it was my choice.
Wouldn't I have to search for it in database and manually do each one? We are talking thousands of times here...
So with that plugin I mentioned about do you think it can do the task? It says text not shortcode though but could it do the same thing? I don't really understand it. Thanks

Comment: are you there still?

Comment: I take it you have given up on my question :-(

Comment: Hi, if you follow my first instruction you simply export the database, open it in a text editor, Find and Replace all entries you want to change, then reupload that data to the database. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: By the way I frequently travel for work and am on here for free so please don't expect immediate support. :)

Comment: I backed up my whole site through cPanel backup wizard.
I have now gone to phpmyadmin. Clicked on search. Put in the shortcode and told it to search wp_posts. It came up with thousands of results. How do I replace the text through this? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Hi, you need to re read my instructions. You have to export the database and download it to your computer then follow the rest of the steps I've outlined.